# Sorting out websockets drafts and browsers support

Tags: websocket

At the time of this question, Mozilla says that FF7 implements version 8 (draft 10):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Firefox_7_for_developers#WebSockets

And the latest blog post on Chromium dated 08-01-2011 also says that Chromium supports the same draft 10:

http://blog.chromium.org/2011/08/new-websocket-protocol-secure-and.html

Both leads to the same link:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-10

Then on wikipedia, it says FF7 and Chrome 14 also implements draft 10:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

But when I test FF7 and Chrome 14 on websocket.org

http://websocket.org/echo.html

Chrome 14 passes and FF7 fails.  BTW, IE 9 also fails, but Opera 11.52 passes.  So how I know which version runs on websocket.org and determine if FF7 does indeed implement draft 10?

Comment: Although there is little difference between version 8 and 10, Chrome actually sends a `Sec-WebSocket-Version: 8` header, FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look to the source code of that page you will notice that they are implementing the API like this:

```
  function testWebSocket()
  {
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
    websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
    websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
    websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
    websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
  }
```

But when it comes to firefox you should use in the first line to be able to use it on FF:

```
websocket = new MozWebSocket(wsUri);
```

Sice out friends of FF named it like that :D

Hope this helps!

Example:

```
function connect() {
    if ('WebSocket' in window) {
        websocket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.hostname + ':4502/chat');
    }
    else if ('MozWebSocket' in window) {
        websocket = new MozWebSocket('ws://' + window.location.hostname + ':4502/chat');
    }
    else {
        //not supported
        return;
    }
}
```

[WebSocket versions and backwards compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960500/websocket-versions-and-backwards-compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

the http://websocket.org/echo.html site has been updated - it's working with FF7:

Once you click connect, you'll get a "warning" regarding the MozWebSocket object:
Info: This browser supports WebSocket using the MozWebSocket constructor